# Find all submatrices of a given matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I need to find all possible sub-matrices of a given matrix mxn. I am trying to do this in python and don't want to use numpy. Can we do this using loops only?

Eg: 2x2 matrix

```
Matrix = [
          [1, 2], 
          [3, 4]
         ]

Submatrices =[ [1], 
               [1,2], 
               [2], 
               [3], 
               [4], 
               [3, 4], 
               [[1], [3]], 
               [[2],[4]], 
               [[1,2],[3,4]] ]
```

Comment: What about a 3x3 matrix? Is removing a group of random columns still considered a submatrix? Or should a contiguous section of the matrix be considered a proper submatrix?

Comment: I think you need to implement two functions : `Combination(x,n)` and `SubMatrix(x_start,x_end,y_start,y_end)`. And it should be solved

Comment: @ssm A contiguous section of the matrix should be considered a proper submatrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the matrix

```
Matrix = [
      [1, 2,3], 
      [3, 4,5],
      [5,6,7]
     ]
```

Split into 3 function:

```
def ContinSubSeq(lst):
  size=len(lst)
  for start in range(size):
    for end in range(start+1,size+1):
      yield (start,end)

def getsubmat(mat,start_row,end_row,start_col,end_col):
  return [i[start_col:end_col] for i in mat[start_row:end_row] ]

def get_all_sub_mat(mat):
  rows = len(mat)
  cols = len(mat[0])
  for start_row,end_row in ContinSubSeq(list(range(rows))):
    for start_col,end_col in ContinSubSeq(list(range(cols))):
      yield getsubmat(mat,start_row,end_row,start_col,end_col)
```

Run this

```
for i in get_all_sub_mat(Matrix):
  print i
```

Or simpler, put into one function:

```
def get_all_sub_mat(mat):
    rows = len(mat)
    cols = len(mat[0])
    def ContinSubSeq(lst):
        size=len(lst)
        for start in range(size):
            for end in range(start+1,size+1):
                yield (start,end)
    for start_row,end_row in ContinSubSeq(list(range(rows))):
        for start_col,end_col in ContinSubSeq(list(range(cols))):
            yield [i[start_col:end_col] for i in mat[start_row:end_row] ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, but function is not returning all the matrices. if i try it on [[1, 2],[2, 3]] it is only returning [[1]].

Comment: @pankajg Missed one `+1` in `ContinSubSeq`, corrected. Try it now.

Comment: @Chiron This code works as expected. Amazing. But then can you please explain this in algorithmic steps ? I am having trouble understanding the yield.

Comment: @Karthik The idea is to enumerate all possible (StartRow,EndRow) and (StartCol,EndCol) pairs. Then slice the mat row-wise and col-wise. "Yield" is  the same as returning an Array[ ], but faster. You can take 'yield' as 'throw out'.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function allow to extract matrix from matrix, and i us'it for extract all possible combinaison, you will find the script,
 this script solve your problem

```
def extract(mat, n, n1, m, m1): 
    l=[]
    for i in range(n-1, n1):
        r=[]
        for j in range(m-1, m1):
            if mat[i][j] != []:
                r.append(mat[i][j])
        l.append(r)
return l

# set 1 in i1 and j1 
# set dimension+1 in i2 and j2
res = []
for i1 in range(1, 3):
    for i2 in range(1,3):
        for j1 in range(1, 3):
            for j2 in range(1, 3):
                li= extract(mat, i1,i2,j1,j2)
                if li !=[] and i2 >= i1 and j2>=j1 :
                   res.append(li)

print res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_sub(r, c, mat): # returns all sub matrices of order r * c in mat
    arr_of_subs = []
    if (r == len(mat)) and (c == len(mat[0])):
            arr_of_subs.append(mat)
            return arr_of_subs
    for i in range(len(mat) - r + 1):
        for j in range(len(mat[0]) - c + 1):
            temp_mat = []
            for ki in range(i, r + i):
                temp_row = []
                for kj in range(j, c + j):
                    temp_row.append(mat[ki][kj])
                temp_mat.append(temp_row)
            arr_of_subs.append(temp_mat)
    return arr_of_subs
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using functions...

```
m = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
r = 3
c = 4

x = 0
while x < r:
    y = x+1
    while y <= r:
        a = 0
        while a < c:
            b = a+1
            while b <= c:
                sm = []
                for i in m[x:y]:
                    sm.append(i[a:b])
                print(sm)
                count += 1
                b += 1
            a += 1
        y += 1
    x += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer as of right now is not sufficient. Please avoid posting code-only answers. As you might have no trouble understanding the code, others might struggle. Please add some explanation to it.
Also, check out the beginner tour, it's quite nice and you get an achievement: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

```
def printMatrix(arr,r1,c1,r2,c2):
  for i in range(r1,r2+1):
    for j in range(c1,c2+1):
      print(arr[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
      
def allSubmatrix(arr):
  m,n = len(arr), len(arr[0])
  for r1 in range(m):
    for c1 in range(n):
      for r2 in range(r1,m):
        for c2 in range(c1,n):
          printMatrix(arr,r1,c1,r2,c2)  # you can do anything with your submatrix here
          print()
```